# Cannot install GeoPandas

Tags: python, installation, geopandas, debian

I've installed Anaconda with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 libxtst6
bash /home/bera/Downloads/Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Then trying to install GeoPandas package with:

```
conda install geopandas

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
```

So I have some incompatibe version? I try to update with:

```
conda update -n base conda
conda update --all
```

Which seems to work but I get the same error when I try to install geopandas.

What is causing the error and how can I solve it to be able to install GeoPandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time when facing an issue with installing some Python Packages via [`conda install package-name`](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/) I always try to install it via [`pip install package-name`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/).

So, you may try to install the GeoPandas with

```
pip install geopandas
```

You can find more information at [Installing package not found in conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009966/installing-package-not-found-in-conda) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `conda-forge` channel. Packages are updated more frequently there:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas

or

You can install all packages at the same time

for example

conda install --channel conda-forge gdal, rasterio, geopandas

Comment: you can add anaconda to path on windows and having manager permissions